# Error using ResultSet. It only returns a single row

Tags: java, jdbc

I have created a program that is used to view the content of a database that contains more than 300 entries. But only get the first one:

```
public static Comics[] verTodo() throws SQLException
{
    int posicion = 0;
    String sentenciaSql = "SELECT * from comics.comicsbbdd";

    Comics comic []= null;

    ResultSet rs = DBManager.getComic(sentenciaSql);

    try {
        if(rs.last()) {
            comic = new Comics[(rs.getRow())];
            System.out.println();
//              rs.beforeFirst();

            do
            {
                String nombre = rs.getString("nomComic");
                String numero = rs.getString("numComic");
                String variante = rs.getString("nomVariante");
                String firma = rs.getString("firma");
                String editorial = rs.getString("nomEditorial");
                String formato = rs.getString("formato");
                String procedencia = rs.getString("procedencia");
                String anioPubli = rs.getString("anioPubli");
                String guionista = rs.getString("nomGuionista");
                String dibujante = rs.getString("nomDibujante");
                comic[posicion] = new Comics(nombre,numero,variante,firma,
                editorial,formato,procedencia,anioPubli,guionista,dibujante);
                posicion++;
                
            }
            while(rs.next());
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
    return comic;
}
```

All this using javaFX and the database is in mysql. Thank you very much for the help.

EDIT

I have managed to get it to work, but clearly the code is ugly, I have tried to improve it, but when I do, the entire content of the database is no longer visible:

```
public static Comics[] verTodo() throws SQLException
{
    int posicion = 0;
    String sentenciaSql = "SELECT * from comics.comicsbbdd";

    Comics comic []= null;

    ResultSet rs = DBManager.getComic(sentenciaSql);

    try {
        if(rs.last()) {
            comic = new Comics[(rs.getRow())];
            rs.beforeFirst();

            if(rs.first())
            {
                do
                {
                    String nombre = rs.getString("nomComic");
                    String numero = rs.getString("numComic");
                    String variante = rs.getString("nomVariante");
                    String firma = rs.getString("firma");
                    String editorial = rs.getString("nomEditorial");
                    String formato = rs.getString("formato");
                    String procedencia = rs.getString("procedencia");
                    String anioPubli = rs.getString("anioPubli");
                    String guionista = rs.getString("nomGuionista");
                    String dibujante = rs.getString("nomDibujante");
                    comic[posicion] = new Comics(nombre,numero,variante,firma,editorial,formato,procedencia,anioPubli,guionista,dibujante);
                    System.out.println(comic[posicion].toString());
                    posicion++;
                }
                while(rs.next());
            }
            System.out.println(comic.length);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
    return comic;
}
```

Comment: Don't try to do fancy things with cursors. If you must return an array, fill a `List` and then turn it into an array. btw your class name is wrong: singular entities should have [singular names](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dunni has pointed out the right thing in the answer.I have also upvoted the same.

---

Here I am just giving a suggestion.

You can achieve the same thing just using `list` and the code will be more easy.You will not have to do any of the `cursor` moving just to get the no of rows from the `resultset`.

Using `List` you will not need to worry about the size of `resultset`(For your case it is applicable) .
Also, now you can simply use `while-loop` to iterate the `resultset`

Below is an example:

```java
Comics comic []=null;
List<Comic> list = new ArrayList<>();
ResultSet rs = DBManager.getComic(sentenciaSql);

try {
    while(rs.next()){
        
        //fetch your values

        //add a object to the list;
        list.add(new Comics(nombre,numero,variante,firma,editorial,formato,procedencia,anioPubli,guionista,dibujante))
    }
             
}catch(Exception ex){
   e.printStackTrace(); // Try to use relevant Exception classes instead of calling the 'Exception' itself. 
}

// Convert the list to array
comic =  new Comics[list.size()];
comic = list.toArray(comic);
```

After adding all the values in the list just convert it to your `array`.

Comment: And what is the "try without anything" block good for?

Comment: Sorry, My mistake .Forgot to copy paste the same from vs :p. Updated it

Comment: id works!! Thanks, i need to reed the code and understand why, but, thank you so much

Comment: The code is easy to maintain if you don't move around the cursor. In your case i.e `rs.last()`

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
if(rs.last()) {
```

moves the cursor of the ResultSet to the last row, so that's the only one you then get (since after the last row, there are no further rows and `rs.next()` will not return any more rows).

See the Javadoc for that method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#last()

Comment: I have managed to get it to work, but clearly the code is ugly, I have tried to improve it, but when I do, the entire content of the database is no longer visible

Comment: Probably because you `catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(); }`. Don't swallow/hide exceptions.